# CSS advanced oval shape

Tags: css, sass

I have problem with creating this shape in css:

[image: oval shape image]

I tried after & bottom with skew but cannot make it oval and there is content below it.

Comment: Please include your code as a snippet. Make it easy for folks to help you.

Comment: you can use :after , border-radius and overflow . where after is much wider and easier to shape  hidding side's edges, a mix of linear and radial-gradient can do too  else SVG will do perfectly.

Comment: is it an arrow at the end ?

Answer (score 0):

Play with border-radius settings. Hope this helps.

```css
.oval {
width: 100px;
height: 150px;
background-color: lightblue;
border-bottom-right-radius: 70px 25px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 70px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

Comment: Well, its not complete answer, since my shape have sharp endings... I tried this already